# Create Boxes Dynamically on a Page

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble adding boxes dynamically to an HTML canvas. There should be a random amount of boxes, in random positions, of random colors.
The goal of what I am doing with the boxes is to be able to move them. 
Essentially I am really lost.

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Ramdom Boxes</title>
        <script src="A2Q1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
    //when page is loaded create a bunch of boxes randomly throughout the page
    //get the body element of the document
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    //create the canvas tag
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.height = 666;
    canvas.width = 1346;
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //create the random boxes and append onto the canvas
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);

    var boxes = [];
    for(var i=0;i<randNum;i++){
        boxes[i].height = 50;
        boxes[i].width = 50;
        boxes[i].x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1346 - boxes[i].width));
        boxes[i].y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (666 - boxes[i].height));

        boxes[i].colour = '#'+ Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<boxes.length;i++){
        context.fillStyle = colour;
        context.fillRect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, , boxes[i].height); 
    }

    //append the canvas onto the body 
    body.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

Nothing is showing up on the page, through debugging it seems it is having issues with the properties. I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Which errors are thrown in console?

Comment: @BramVanroy Well it was throwing errors it gets to the  boxes[i].something (.width, .x, .y, etc). But now its not even showing any errors and its not displaying any boxes.

Comment: You have two commas on the sixth from last line., after `boxes[i].y`. Are those meant to be like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use masonry jquery plugin to sort boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.fillStyle = colour;
```

Did you mean

```
context.fillStyle = boxes[i].colour;
```